# Add Swagger servlet support to project with Swagger and Jaxrs

Tags: java, servlets, embedded-jetty, swagger

I have an Embedded Jetty application (in Java) with Jaxrs + Swagger that works just fine (finally). It implements basic REST operations (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE) on simple JSON objects.

I have several HTTPServlets that handle some of my REST APIs and would like to add Swagger support. The only example of setting up Swagger + Servlets that I can find uses web.xml for configuration.

Unfortunately, my application doesn't use web.xml, it configures everything in Java.

1) Is it possible for Swagger to support both Jaxrs AND Servlets? (Are they mutually exclusive?)
2) If possible, how can I configure Swagger to support Servlets in Java?

Here's my annotated API:

```
@Api(value = "myService",
        description = "My Config Service API",
        produces = "application/json",
        consumes = "application/json")
@Path("/env")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public class MyServiceResource
{
    @GET
    @Path("/thing/{thingName}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Gets Thing", response = Thing.class)
    public Response getThing(
            @PathParam("thingName") String thingName) throws IOException
    {
        return blah blah blah
    }

    blah blah blah
}
```

Here's the Swagger config file:

```
@WebServlet(name = "SwaggerJaxrsConfig", loadOnStartup = 1)
public class SwaggerJaxrsConfig extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) {
        super.init(servletConfig);
        SwaggerConfig swaggerConfig = new SwaggerConfig();
        ConfigFactory.setConfig(swaggerConfig);
        swaggerConfig.setBasePath("http://localhost:8002");
        swaggerConfig.setApiVersion("1.0.0");
        ScannerFactory.setScanner(new DefaultJaxrsScanner());
        ClassReaders.setReader(new DefaultJaxrsApiReader());
    }
}
```

Here's some file that does some more Swagger setup:

```
public class ServiceApplication extends Application
{
    HashSet<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

    public ServiceApplication()
    {
        singletons.add(new MyServiceResource());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
    {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();
        resources.add(ApiDeclarationProvider.class);
        resources.add(ApiListingResourceJSON.class);
        resources.add(ResourceListingProvider.class);
        resources.add(MyServiceResource.class);
        return resources;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons()
    {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

Here's the server code that ties all of the above together:

```
public class MyService {
    private Server server;

    public MyService() {
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {
        server = new Server();
        SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
        connector.setPort(8002);
        server.addConnector(connector);

        // Setup web handler
        final ResourceHandler webResourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
        webResourceHandler.setDirectoriesListed(false);
        webResourceHandler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{"index.html"});
        webResourceHandler.setResourceBase("webapp");

        // Create servlet context
        final ServletContextHandler servletContext = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        servletContext.addEventListener(new DefaultResteasyBootstrap());
        servletContext.setContextPath("/");

        // Setup Swagger handlers
        servletContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new SwaggerJaxrsConfig()), "");

        // Add MyService Servlet
        final ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(new HttpServletDispatcher());
        servletHolder.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", MyServiceResource.class.getName());
        servletContext.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");

        // Add Admin Servlet
        final ServletHolder adminServletHolder = new ServletHolder(new HttpServletDispatcher());
        servletContext.addServlet(adminServletHolder, "/admin/*");

        // Add Admin Servlets
        servletContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new PingServlet()), "/ping");
        servletContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ThreadDumpServlet()), "/threadDump");

        final HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{
                webResourceHandler,     // Web handler
                servletContext,         // Servlet handler
                new DefaultHandler()}); // Default handler returns 404 (NOT FOUND) for anything else

        server.setHandler(handlers);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: So according to Swagger samples (and the web) the way to get Swagger working for Servlets is to put the following in your webl.xml file: github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/Servlet-Quickstart. I've been trying to reproduce this in Java with things like: "servletContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DefaultServletReaderConfig()), "");" and by adding DefaultServletReaderConfig.class to my ServiceApplication class (but this causes jaxrs exceptions).

Comment: UPDATE: I've gotten clarification from the Swagger Google group that Swagger can only support Jaxrs OR Servlets, but not both simultaneously, because there can only be one reader class active. I've also gotten advice on how to configure Swagger to use servlets without a web.xml file... but have yet to get this to work.

Comment: This is a little late but which implementation did you end up with? I'm trying the HttpServlet option and configuring everything in java but it seems few examples use this option. Almost all examples go through the web.xml option